# One way anonimization - entity join required

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography

I have a stream of customer data that comes at a random time during a day. Each message has customerId (which considered to be highly sensitive). 
I am not allowed to store customerId anywhere in the plain format I need to anonymize customerId field, I have the following conditions:

1. I never need to decrypt and see a plain value
2. I need to group all messages by customer id - join all messages together - hashing + salt - doesn't work because it provides a different result for the same value which makes it impossible to join.
3. Hashing without salt considered to be unsafe because of potential attacks. Dictionary, Rainbow tables, Bruteforce etc.

Which method considered to be most secure given following the requirements?

Comment: "Hashing without salt considered to be unsafe because of potential attacks. Dictionary, Rainbow tables, Bruteforce etc." Which dictionary contains your customer numbers? What's  the keyspace here? Hashing with a constant shared salt defeats rainbow tables just fine (adversaries have to compute a table specifically for your salt). But that doesn't help of course if we're talking, say, int32.

Comment: @Peter you probably didn't get my question. I don't need to validate hash, I will never have access to the plain value to validate it. All I need is to generate anonymized value (hashed or encrypted). What is simplest and safest method achieving that?

Comment: I guess I didn't make myself clear. You mention hashing with unique salts for each message and hashing without a salt. But you haven't considered hashing with a single constant salt (which is enough to subvert existing rainbow tables). If the space of all customer IDs is large, any hash function will do. If it's small, such as int32, it's feasible to just compute all possible hashes and you need a hashing algorithm with a secret component (HMAC for instance). Which one is "safest" and "simplest" is for you to decide.